# Return "value" attribute of a tr tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table id="messages" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
    </tr>
    <tr value="1">
      //data
    </tr>
    <tr value="2">
      //data
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need some jquery that will return the val attribute of the clicked tr.  I already have jquery that will return an array of all teh inclosed td within the tr but i still need the "value" saved to a variable.  Any help?

Comment: A non-input element should not have a `value` attribute; instead use a [custom `data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute to maintain valid HTML (albeit only valid in HTML5).

Comment: jQuery can access `data-` attributes with `.data()` even in non-HTML5 browsers.

Comment: @Blazemonger: I never said it couldn't, I just said that the `data-*` attributes aren't valid in HTML, unless it's HTML5.

Comment: @DavidThomas: The one exception to that rule that I know of is `li` elements, where the `value` attribute is valid, oddly enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not advisable to add `value` attributes to non-input elements, because that makes no sense to the browser. Change `<tr value="1">` to `<tr data-value="1">` and access it using `$tr.data('value')` (where `$tr` is a jQuery object for *one* unique table row).

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: note: he may also need the code to get the correct tr

Comment: @NathanKoop Clarified, thanks.

Comment: Tried this but I am getting the error:                                                     TypeError: $(...).data is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

alert($(this).data('value'));

Comment: To be fair, most of the current browsers will handle the attribute sanely in the interest of enabling polyfills if nothing else. (Heck, AngularJS seems to depend on this.) It's still not a very good idea for forward compatibility though.

Comment: @Mildfire what version of jQuery?

Comment: This works perfectly. The only thing is even if data('VALUE') where 'VALUE' is uppercase, when you go to collect the data using $(rowInstance).data('value')   'value' needs to be lowercase. for some reason it will only look for the lowercase value of whatever your value actually was.

Answer (score 3):

You would use `$(this).attr('value')` to get the attribute, but some browsers might not support a non-standard attribute like this. It would be better to use a data attribute:

```
<tr data-value="1">
```

Then you can get the value using `$(this).data('value')`.

Comment: I'd be very, very, very surprised if a browser exists / ever will exist that will reject invalid attributes but accept `data-*` ones. As far as I understand it, the rationale behind them is mostly that the prefix forms a namespace where W3C / the browser vendors will never introduce attributes of their own. (While it's possible that for some reason someone might decide to define a `value` attribute on `tr` tags and suddenly your page starts doing something strange in that browser.)

Comment: @millimoose The difference is, you can retrieve a form element's `value` by using the `.value` property in vanilla JavaScript. `tr`, on the other hand, doesn't have a `.value` property. https://jsfiddle.net/0xnkmnqn/

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery

`var variable = $('tr').val();`

Or

`var variable = $('tr').attr('value');`

Even when it's incorrect to assign a value to a tr element